# How to pause between action in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

I want to pause between performing mouse-down and mouse-move action. 
In my functionality i need to hold mouse down for 500ms and then move, is there any option to pause for 500ms after mousedown event and then move.
I already applied browser.sleep()

Comment: what's wrong with `browser.sleep(500);` ?

Comment: Can you show how you applied browser.sleep? (i.e paste what you have so far)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here is how I solved it (not the cleanest, but not sure how else):

CoffeeScript:

```
browser.actions().mouseDown($('#someElement')).perform().then (element) ->
  browser.sleep(500).then ->
    browser.actions().mouseMove($('body')).perform()
```

Note `actions()` and `perform()` are used twice - `mouseDown()`, `mouseMove()` and `mouseUp()` are only exposed through `WebDriver.ActionSequence`